# Terraform contains function not working as expected

Tags: terraform, terraform-modules

I want to filter my list of strings in Terraform based on the 'app' and 'db' tiers. However, the contains function returns an empty result with the string 'app'

```
variable "tiers" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["app-1", "app-2", "db-1", "db-2"]
}

output "iterate-apps" {
  value = [
    for app_id in var.tiers : app_id
    if contains(["app"], app_id)    
  ]
}
```

Actual :

`+ iterate-apps = []`

Expected :
`iterate-apps = [ + "app-1", "app-2" ]`

correct me what is wrong in the above code ?

Comment: I think you can replace `contain` by `startwith` and see what happen.

Change: if contains(["app"], app_id)  to if startsWith("app", app_id)

Comment: I am getting empty output with `startwith` function. However what if tomorrow  my string changes to "something-app-1" @KienBuiTrung

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its better to use [strcontains](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/strcontains), rather than `contains`:

```
output "iterate-apps" {
  value = [
    for app_id in var.tiers : app_id
    if strcontains(app_id, "app")    
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression

```
output "iterate-apps" {
  value = [
    for app_id in var.tiers : app_id
    if length(regexall("(?i)\\bapp\\b", app_id)) > 0
  ]
}
```